# ASP.NET Core, handle expected exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on a pretty simple CRUD controller in ASP.NET core and now I'm facing the issue, that I need to handle errors like working with an not existing entity (returning a 404) or creating a duplicate (returning a 400).

So now I'm wondering what is the most idiomatic way in ASP.NET Core to fetch *expected* errors and return the correct status code for them.

One way could be to throw exceptions in the services that are responsible for the actual CRUD and catch them inside of the controller:

```cs
/// Inside service...
public void Create(Entity entityDetails) {
  if (entityAlreadyExists(entityDetails)) {
    throw new EntityDuplicateException();
  }
  // ...
}

/// Inside controller...
[HttpPost("{operatorClientId}")] 
public void CreateEntity(Entity entityDetails) {
  try {
   _entityService.CreateEntity(entityDetails);    

    return Ok();
  } catch (EntityDuplicateException e) {  // Some self defined exception type
    return BadRequest(/* Some details about the entity */);
  }
}
```

This seems a bit repetitive to me because a lot of code would be always the same, but it makes clear what to expect from the API at the first glance. I think this could also get a bit messy when more exceptions need to be handled.

Another approach could be to implement a method for UseExceptionHandler, where all exception types are handled like:

```
switch (exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error)
{
    case EntityDuplicateException e:
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        // More details to response here
        break;
    case EntityNotFoundException e:
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        // More details to response here
        break;
    case {} e:
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        // More details to response here
        break;
}
```

This would be a single place for the handling of expected (and unexpected) exceptions. But you cannot see at first glance what the controller will return. And it can get harder to obtain all required information for a meaningful error message in the response (in the controller every information is directly available, with the ExceptionHandler I need to wrap all information into the exception).

Comment: You could also return a Response type from the services that includes a Success/Fail field, Fail reason and Result instead of Exceptions. Then you could just evaluate that Response and create the appropriate API responses from it. Making it a generic type, you could also avoid a good amount of duplicate code. While this would be very similar to using Exceptions, it avoids the overhead of creating exception contexts.

Comment: You can create a middleware that will catch same exceptions everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

An exception, as its name applies, should only be used in exceptional circumstances, [not for control flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why). An entity not being found or already existing is not exceptional; it's a common case that you should be handling explicitly in your data-access code. On the other hand, a deadlock in your database is.

Instead of having your data-access methods throw exceptions, make them return something like a Tuple of `(bool success, string errorMessage)`. In the controller, check the `success` member - if it's `false`, return the `errorMessage` to the caller.

As for your global exception handler, leave it generic. It should do little more than log all exceptions to a central location, so that you can inspect those logs regularly to determine whether your app really is encountering exceptional circumstances on a regular basis - in which case you need to fix it.